# Cakephp 3.x Custom Query Pagination

Tags: mysql, cakephp, pagination, cakephp-3.0

I used in Cakephp 2.x Custom Query Pagination.
Now I am trying to migrate a project to Cake 3.

The manual of Cake 3 does not mention Custom Query Pagination any more,
and it seems, that the model function paginate / paginateCount which are used for the Custom Query Pagination are not called.

Does anyone know, if this is dropped in Cake 3 ?
If so, how can I do pagination with custom queries in cake 3 ?

Comment: did you find a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public function index()
{
    $query = $this->Articles->find('popular')->where(['author_id' => 1]);
    $this->set('articles', $this->paginate($query));
}
```

The doc page: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/pagination.html

Comment: I believe the OP is asking how to do pagination when a custom/raw SQL query is run, not when the query is built using the framework.

Answer (score 1):

Try to read these :

[Controller/Component/Pagination](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/pagination.html)

[View/Helper/Paginator](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/paginator.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
$bookmarks = TableRegistry::get('Bookmarks');

    $this->paginate['contain'] = [
        'Users' => function (\Cake\ORM\Query $query) {
            return $query->select(['email'])
                         ->where([]);
        }
    ];

    $bookmarks = $this->paginate($bookmarks);
```