# CakePHP 3.x Specify a Different Count Query for Pagination

Tags: cakephp, count, pagination, query-builder, cakephp-3.x

I am trying to customize the pagination query for CakePHP I am using a Model based around a view. The view has some complex calculations in it and when the pagination runs it takes about 3 seconds to pull the 20 rows or so. Then it is running the same view wrapped in a count for the count used in pagination. I can run a simple table count on another table which would cut the load times in half but I am unable to find a simple way to customize a seperate query to run for the counts. Is this even possible?

I know another user asked this question but it was never answered.

[Cakephp 3.x Custom Query Pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29621449/cakephp-3-x-custom-query-pagination)

I have tried the way that is used to work in 2.x using a custom **paginateCount** function in both the entity and the table and neither works I dug through the API a bit but couldn't find anything related to the count specifically.

Comment: what have you tried? https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/pagination.html

Comment: I have updated my post. I have tried the ways that used to work in CakePHP 2.x days and I have tried looking through the API component for pagination.

Comment: did you read the documentation at https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/pagination.html

Comment: @MontrealDevOne Much like you asked two days ago... yes I have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use the query builder's `counter()` method to provide a callback that returns the number of records based on your custom query.

```
$query->counter(function (\Cake\ORM\Query $query) {
    // assuming $this uses \Cake\ORM\Locator\LocatorAwareTrait
    $OtherTable = $this->getTableLocator()->get('Other');
    $otherQuery = $OtherTable->find();

    // ...

    return $otherQuery->count();
});
```

The `$query` argument will be a clone of the query itself.  You can either modify that one, or construct a completely new query.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Returning the Total Count of Records](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#returning-the-total-count-of-records)**
- **[API > \Cake\ORM\Query::counter()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.5/class-Cake.ORM.Query.html#_counter)**

Comment: I will take a look at this tomorrow.